# Is there a different manner to do the authentication with the new spring security using jwt?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I try to do the security of my project adapting the baeldung documentation and the previous code, and I want to know the normal method of this. I have the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        return httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()

                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/create", "/api/login", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }


}
```

then I have this token provider

```
@Component
public class JtwTokenProvider {
    @Value("${app.jwt-secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwt-expiration-milliseconds}")
    private int jwtExpirationInMs;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();

        return token;
    }

    public String getUsernameOfJwt(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token){
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;

        }catch (SignatureException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT signature");
        }catch (MalformedJwtException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid JWT token");
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Expired JWT token");
        }catch (UnsupportedJwtException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Unsupported JWT token");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "JWT claims string is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

The token filter is the same and this manner is okay? What others exist?

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JtwTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Get JWT from request
        String token = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && tokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            // Get username from token
            String username = tokenProvider.getUsernameOfJwt(token);

            // Load user associated with the token
            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            //Set the authentication in the SecurityContext
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.replace("Bearer ", "");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I used the userdetails service

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(
                () -> new NotFoundException("User not found"));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), getAuthority(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthority(Set<Role> roles){
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Finally here is my authentication, this is safe? what is the standart manner of do the same?

```
@Service
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JtwTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;


    @Override
    public JwtAuthResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);

        return new JwtAuthResponse(jwt);
    }
}
```

I was waiting your responses thanks :D

Comment: Spring Security has a full implementation in how to handle JWTs, so you dont have to write custom filters, and custom validation etc https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1 use the spring security implementation so you can focus on logic, instead of "is it safe"

Comment: take a look at spring-security official sample of jwt-secured resource-server: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login

Comment: Thanks :D I am going to read all documentation of you comment